# I don't see changes when using :has()

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I recently discovered the `:has()` pseudo-class. When I tried to test it I didn't see any changes. I really don't know why.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
}

section:has(div) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1></h1>
</section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Comment: did you check this ? https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas ?

Comment: Does any section in your code have a div? No! So why would `section:has(div)` work?

Answer (score 1):

None of the sections in your code has a div inside it.

This snippet changes the background if it has an h1.

[Note as at time of posting this, Firefox does not support :has by default, the user has to change a setting].

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
}

section:has(h1) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <h1></h1>
  </section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I USE FIREFOX :0. Really thanks for help:)

Comment: You can use https://caniuse.com/ to check what CSS is implemented. But in any case you'd need a div element inside one of those sections for your initial code to work.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the working example:**
**section:has(div)** checks if there is any div inside the section exists then it will apply the stylings

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 10px;
}

section:has(div) {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</body>

</html>
```